# What does this sentence means?

Tags: translation

> Litter adversely affects the environment. **Be it** littering along the
>   road, on the streets or by the litter bins, toxic materials or
>   chemicals in the litter can be blown or washed into rivers, or oceans and eventually pollutes the waterways.

How can I understand these sentence properly, I do not really get the highlighted part "be it". is it the same meaning as **whether**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex sentence with an asyndetic conditional clause. In the clause there is a subject-verb inversion. The verb /be/ is in the Present Subjunctive. The sentence can be re-written: 'If it be ...'.
Similar sentences with such inversion: 'Were I you, I would recommend the following...' , 'Be it so, ...'.
Nowadays the Subjunctive Mood is used sometimes in Formal English.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is like a mind opener to me :) , is it too formal to use in an essay? I mean I kinda feel that it is more proper for more formal writing such as a scientific article or things like that.

Comment: Though it is a bit bookish, I think, this construction is rather expressive and appropriate for an ecological essay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does basically have the same meaning as "whether" *in this context*.

```
Be it littering along the road, on the streets or by the litter bins,
```

Means the same thing as:

```
Whether it's littering along the road, on the streets or by the litter bins,
```